# given quantity and price, get sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

The sheet contains two parts, first part shows employees sell what products and the amount of each product, second part is product's price, now given employee Tom, calculate how much money does he sell products. The result should be 5*2+4*1+1*2=16, but I don't know how to write excel formula. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Look at `SUMPRODUCT` function and come back when you can't make it work.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald I know how to calculate product1, =SUMPRODUCT((A2:A9=J2)*(F2:F9=B2)*C2:C9*G2:G9),but I don't know what products does Tom sell and how to SUM them up.

Comment: sorry, the above formula is not correct. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(T(IF({1},$B$2:$B$6)),$F$2:$G$9,2,)*$C$2:$C$6*($A$2:$A$6=J2))`

Somebody gives the above solution, it's great.

The answer seems to tell that(I just presume, not sure):

1. `IF({1},$B$2:$B$6)` convert cells to static array.
2. the first argument `lookup_value` in `VLOOKUP` can be array.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a helper column in column D to get the price total for each row you can do it with sumif:

Put this in D2 and drag down:

```
=INDEX(G:G,MATCH(B2,F:F,0),1)*C2
```

Then this in K2:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,J2,D:D)
```

You can drag this down as well if you want to add another name to total in the next line.

[image]

Comment: thanks very much, I will accept it if no better solution comes out. I wish to calculate it without helper column.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get a filtered array the same size as the first group so be able to sumproduct the corresponding values correctly.

Comment: look at the answer I post.